# Prime sign not correctly displayed on uppercase letters

Tags: apostrophe

I have this definition in which I want to use uppercase letters with prime symbols attached, but the prime sign does not seem to display correctly. Is this a feature of the language, or is it a culprit of my macros, settings and templates? Please do not go into too much detail if possible, I am a beginner in LaTeX. Thank you in advance.

Here is what I use at the moment and how it displays:

```
\(G\prime = (V\prime, E\prime)\)
```

[image: prime_sign_uppercase_formatting]

Comment: the syntax is `G'` not `G\prime`

Comment: Use `'` not `\prime`, it is the same as `^{\prime} `

Comment: It sounds, from the answer and comments, that the same would occur with lowercase. If so, worth amending the question?

Answer (score 5):

You have in mind

```
\(G^{\prime} = (V^{\prime}, E^{\prime})\)
```

or, much easier,

```
\(G'=(V',E')\)
```